Ending specific task/process with batch script if it's found in tasklist
For context, I found this among XAMPP batch files:
@echo off 
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "PID_LIST="

for /f "tokens=2" %%V in ('tasklist.exe ^| findstr /i "%1" 2^>NUL') do @set "PID_LIST=!PID_LIST! /PID %%V"

if defined PID_LIST (
  taskkill.exe /F %PID_LIST%
) else (
  echo Process %1 not running
)

SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
exit

I wish to write a single script to end all tasks related to my webserver. I have a basic understanding of batch, so I have been able to interpret most of what this script does:

Delayed expansion is needed for the for loop
The for loop gets the second token (PID) from tasklist and saves it into a variable, where the task is given by paramater 1.
If the task is found it is ended with taskkill

Based on this I came so far:
@echo off
cd /D %~dp0
for /f "tokens=2" %%V in ('tasklist.exe ^| findstr /i "httpd.exe" 2^>NUL') do taskkill.exe /pid /f %%V
for /f "tokens=2" %%V in ('tasklist.exe ^| findstr /i "mysql" 2^>NUL') do taskkill.exe /pid /f %%V
:: etc

But I would ideally collapse this into one for loop. How could I add or logic to the findstr expression?
I also have a few questions, which I can't find quick answers to anywhere. Can anyone answer these in the comments?

In my script, do I need to EnableDelayedExpansion?
What is the purpose of set "PID_LIST=", leaving the variable undefined?
I don't fully understand the command pipe findstr: what is the meaning of 2^>NUL, and why does > need to be careted?
How does the set command append to the variable with !VARIABLE!?


Could you please clarify why you are matching a part basename with extension in the first loop, and a substring of a filename in the second. It is better for helpers to fully understand exactly what the processes are you are trying to close. Also, if you are just closing them upon discovering they are open, you do not really need their PID's.

@Compo Because there might be more than one process related to MySQL. Besides these I also end Apache James and FileZilla, but the latter also has a function for that in its executable.

Surely you know the names of all of the processes related to your webserver.


Yes in the first script; no in the second.
To ensure that PID_LIST is undefined, in case it has been left defined from some prior operation.
2>nul redirects error messages from the command to nowhere instead of the console. The carets before the redirectors are escape characters, telling the parser that the redirector is part of the immediately-prior command, not of the for.
When delayedexpansion is in effect, !var! retrieves the current value of the variable, whereas %var% is replaced by the value of the variable at the time that the code block (parenthesised sequence of lines) was parsed.

Tips:
Always use a setlocal flavour to avoid environment clutter. If setlocal is used (usually directly after the @echo off line) then when the batch ends, any changes to the environment are undone, so successive batches will not accumulate changes and the environment state whenever a batch is started will always be the same.
See Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link
To accomplish the or you seek, use
findstr /i /c:"httpd.exe" /c:"mysql"

(and you can add any number of /c:"literalstring" elements.
findstr can also be supplied with
findstr /i "httpd.exe mysql"

in this case; the space in the literal meaning string or string. If you want to target a string that contains a space, use the /c:"this string" /c:"that string" syntax.
See findstr /? from the prompt for more documentation - or see thousands of examples on SO

Nice, thank you for the thorough explanation, especially on the smaller questions I had. It's hard to find answers about Window shell, if you don't know what everything is called.

httpd.exe is technically incorrect, in the examples above, because in it, the . character is a wildcard. It should really be httpd\.exe, to match a literal period.

@compo: Well, true, Could compensate by adding the /L switch. Also, the findstr would find any executable named *httpd.exe* or *mysql* - and to make absolutely sure, you'd need to insert for %%q in (httpd.exe mysql) do if "%%V"=="%%q" before taskkill…, Then you'd note that mysql is not an executable name, and you might even like to tackle the presence of executable x y httpd.exe or httpd,exe x.exe, which will/won't be detected by tokens=2.

That's correct @Magoo, hence the reason I commented under the question proper. The OP should know exactly the names of the processes for their own webserver, and if they don't, killing them based only on substrings, (even if they were sure there were no spaces in their names), is potentially damaging.
